# Python program to run on PC

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe

I have written a python program which gets an input from user then runs a code and returns values, it is being saved as *.py* extension.

I want to run it on different PC which doesn't have python. Is there a way to save it or compile it to *.exe*?

**Note:** I am used to writing C programs which are directly compiled (code blocks) and gives .exe

Comment: You could use cx_Freeze module or py2exe, but it is not as simple as on C.

Answer (score 1):

Pip install PyInstaller and then in the command prompt do PyInstaller yourscript.py > nameofprogramyouwant.exe

Answer (score 0):

The C code that you are used to writing compiles into .exe as you already know. However, not every PC can run .exe files, ie. those running on Mac, and other operating systems. So in short, the answer is no. However, there is a branch of Python known as Jython, which runs on the JVM (Java Virtual Machine) allowing it to work on any operating system with any PC. The ability to work on any machine in any environment is one of the most prized features of Java, and with Jython (which is compiled to Java code) you are able to emulate this key feature with python.

Comment: Being an interpreted language, Python is as platform independent as Java. That is, if there is a Python interpreter for that platform, it can execute Python scripts, just as Java requires a JRE.

Comment: @dtk While that's certainly true, Java has a much bigger commitment to the WORE (Write once, run anywhere) principle. Almost everything, from gas station terminals, mobile phones, Android, routers, mainframes, and even websites all come pre-equipped with the facilities to run code. In-fact most of the heavy lifting in your Python code is done in the C language in the background, and typically imports a ton of C modules. Java modules in the other hand, are all written entirely in Java.  Python on the other hand is only present on most common platforms like Windows, Mac, Linux distributions.

Answer (score 0):

I use py2exe but options like cx_freeze and pyinstaller are also out there. What goes for mac i beleive there exist a module called py2app ;)

to use py2exe you must first have python 3.4 since it hasnt't recently been updated. After that you need to make a file in which you write

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(windows=["yourfile"])
```

then you need to run the file with the following command - i called the file setup.txt here.

```
py -3.4 setup.txt install
```

remember to write .py if you used a python file
and then you just need one more step

```
py -3.4 setup.txt py2exe
```

and ofcause remeber you need to have py2exe installed. If you haven't before you do anything write in to the comandoprompt

```
pip install py2exe
```

The exe will then be found i the dist folder.

Comment: we don't run mac in our company. Is there like a manual for using py2exe
how exactly do i use it i mean?

Comment: the code below  will do it, so just write it in to a python file and run it and it will create an executeble
------------------------
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(windows=["yourfile.txt"])
------------------------------------------
obviusly only write .txt if you have written it as such, so if you written it as a python file write .py
;)